Стилизовать ползунок


input[type="range"], input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default look */
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer
}
input[type="range"] {
  margin-left:-8px;
  background: #000;
  height: 5px;
  width: 200px
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   height: 20px;
   aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: red
}
<input type="range">



Что та не пойму, как сделать прогресс у ползунка красным

не нужно дублировать вопрос, достаточно отредактировать существующий, добавив в него информацию, если требуется

Полазили бы в DevTools и сами потыкали, за это отвечает ::-webkit-slider-container (хотя всякие генераторы используют ::-webkit-slider-runnable-track).


input[type="range"], input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default look */
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer
}
input[type="range"] {
  margin-left:-8px;
  background: #000;
  height: 5px;
  width: 200px
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   height: 20px;
   aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: red
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-container
{
  background-color: red;
}
<input type="range">




по умолчанию shadow dom отключен, поэтому полазить в devtools и посмотреть может быть проблематично

Не верно написал вопрос, сори. Как сделать ползунок красным целиком, это понятно. Я имел в виду сделать красным до круга, остальное черным. То есть  прогресс сделать красным...
